# How to capture azure service bus message landing time in java client

Tags: time, azureservicebus

I have a azure service bus topic. Multiple producers publish messages to that topic.
In my Java listener class, I need to capture when the message was actually landed in topic.

Appreciate for any pointers.

I did not see any APIs in azure service listener to capture message landed time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`getCreationTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.core.amqp.models.amqpmessageproperties?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-core-amqp-models-amqpmessageproperties-getcreationtime()) method on the AMQP Message Object which can use. Give an object of the [`ServiceBusMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-java-stable) class,  you would need to do

```java
message.getRawAmqpMessage().getProperties().getCreationTime()
```